# nested json parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am using the below code for REST OUTBOUND call and this is working as expected. but i am  trying to parse the second response body but i am unable to retrieve the values under objects.

```
try { 
 var r = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('test', 'post');

 var response = r.execute();
 var responseBody = response.getBody();
 var httpStatus = response.getStatusCode();
 gs.print(response.getBody());
 gs.print(response.getStatusCode());
 var JsonObject = JSON.parse(responseBody);
 var sid = JsonObject.sid; 
 gs.print(sid);

 var r1 = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('x_257605_test.gateways', 'POST' );
 r1.setRequestHeader("X-chkp-sid",sid );
 var response1 = r1.execute();
 var responseBody1 = response1.getBody();
 var httpStatus = response1.getStatusCode()
 gs.print(response1.getBody());
 var JsonObject1 = JSON.parse(responseBody1);
 gs.print(JsonObject1.objects.uid);
}
catch(ex) {
 var message = ex.message;
}
```

please see the sample  json response and i need to extract the values under objects like uid/name/cluster-member-names

Comment: `objects` is an array. You need to provide an index `objects[0].uid`

Comment: thanks for the update, in mycase the array id will increase dynamically so how do i handle

Comment: Loop through the array, eg `JsonObject1.objects.forEach(e => console.log(e.uid))`

Answer (score 0):

the objects property is an array of objects.  This line should change from:

```
gs.print(JsonObject1.objects.uid);
```

to:

```
gs.print(JsonObject1.objects[0].uid);
```

To grab data from the first object's properties, or your could iterate over them if you need to perform an operation on all the objects returned.

Comment: thanks for the update, in mycase the array id will increase dynamically so how do i handle